# i can't properly import unicode module in pycharm

Tags: import, module, pycharm

I tried finding a solution on the internet before coming here.
I can't use the module unicode in my pycharm project. I tried to install it through pycharm and pycharm told me i installed it correctly.

But as you can see in the screenshots, I only have the ".dist-info file" in the site-packages file and not the other file (which should be "unicode" i guess).

How can i install the module properly ? Im using pycharm in windows 10 OS.

Thank you. (if my english is not perfect, sorry, not my first language)

[project imports](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t11Wf.png)

[project tree view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gkNUz.png)

[interpreter settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZTWZB.png)

Comment: Have you tried running your program? What error are you getting?

Comment: No module named unicode. So I can not run my bot.

Comment: Have you tried running  pip install unicode  from the command line? Perhaps remove it from Pycharm's interpreter settings, run that install, and then try adding it back into interpreter settings.  (BTW, folks on StackOverflow prefer that you put in pictures of your screenshots rather than links to the images - all you have to do is click on the 'picture' icon when creating your post and following its instructions.)

Comment: I had. I did it again. No result so far.

And i cant put screenshots in my post yet, my profile is too recent on stack overflow.

Comment: I'm out of ideas. The only thing that looks weird to me is that, as you mentioned, you don't have a file called Unicode, only that dist-info folder. Have you actually tried deleting that folder and then reinstalling? Are you sure that unicode.py didn't get put somewhere else on your disk by accident? If those don't lead anywhere, maybe leave a comment on the Pycharm support forum. Sorry that I don't have more for you.

Comment: I found a solution. Instead of using unicode module, im using unidecode module now, and it is working fine. I'm not sure why I can not use the first one. Thanks for your time and your help.

Comment: Great! Thanks for letting me know. It might help people in the future if you quickly record the solution as an 'Answer' and then mark it as the correct answer.